# Reference Request for Schatten Class Operators being an ideal in the set of Bounded operators.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_class_operator) says that the Schatten class operators in a Hilbert space are an ideal in the space of bounded operators. However, it provides no sources. Can anyone give a reputable source that proves this?

Furthermore, Wikipedia only claims that this is true for $p\geq 1$. Is it also true for the Schatten classes defined with the Schatten quasinorms for $p\in (0,1)$?

Comment: I'd try to look in "Trace Ideals and Their Applications" by Barry Simon. It should be proven in there. All you need is the "Hölder inequality" $\Vert AB \Vert_p,, \Vert BA \Vert_p \leq \Vert A \Vert_p \Vert B \Vert_\infty$, where $\Vert \cdot \Vert_p$ is the Schatten $p$-norm and thus $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ the operator norm.

Comment: I also give a proof in my [thesis](https://www.fernuni-hagen.de/analysis/docs/diplomarbeit_melech.pdf) where it follows from Theorem 14 including the cases $p\in (0,1)$

Comment: I'm late to this, but are there any references for $p$-Schatten ideals for a non-separable Hilbert space?